# How to get Jenkins pipeline script from SCM using an agent instead of Master

Tags: jenkins, version-control

I've a Jenkins agent running on a pc where a BitBucket instance is running and where my Jenkins file is.
Now, I've a pipeline project in Jenkins and I want to use the option "Pipeline script from SCM", but it is always running on the MASTER. How do I manage to run it on the agent instead of the master?

Comment: It is the agent section of the pipeline where you define where to run your pipeline. pipeline { agent } examples here - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Comment: I know, but first it needs to be checked out via SCM. Somehow I need to tell on which agent to run to get the file in the firs place.